# How to parse bad diacritics

Tags: android, json, utf-8

I will parse json string from API due to Android app. When I type URL into web browser then I see this json:
{"id":12345, "title":"Huawei: Sv�?e?ka optick�ch vl�ken"}
The same string I have in my app and I don't know how to parse it. It is czech diacritics. 
The code of my method is here:

```
public static String getJSONString(String url) {
    String jsonString = null;
    HttpURLConnection linkConnection = null;
    try {
        URL linkurl = new URL(url);
        linkConnection = (HttpURLConnection) linkurl.openConnection();
        linkConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        String userCredentials = "xxx:yyyyy";
        linkConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + new String(Base64.encode(userCredentials.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP)));
        linkConnection.setRequestProperty( "Accept-Encoding", "utf-8" ); 
        int responseCode = linkConnection.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            InputStream linkinStream = linkConnection.getInputStream();
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int j = 0;
            while ((j = linkinStream.read()) != -1) {
                baos.write(j);
            }
            byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
            jsonString = new String(data, "utf-8");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (linkConnection != null) {
            linkConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }
    return jsonString;
}
```

Thanks for advance.